# Zoom image and image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can i change the image to another image and zoom the image when the user clicks on it below i have some picture to show how i want the effect to be

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8mHg.gif

white color html:

```
<p class="img-main">
<a href="/eshop/items/152MANH-KNM01S/152MANH-KNM01S-NY.jpg"     class="overlaybox-img" rel="NAVY">
<img src="http://coldcoffee.jp/resources/upload/products/thumbnail2/HM10-T- 1004-WH.jpg">
</a> </p>
<div id="colorsAndAltContainer">
<ul class="">

    <li class="defaultColor selected">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="description">BLACK</div>
                        <div class="rgbColor" data-color="000000"   style="background-color: #000000"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="description">WHITE</div>
                        <div class="rgbColor" data-color="FFFFFF" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>

    <div class="altImages">

  <ul class="alternativeImages">     
   <li class="selected">

        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="T-Shirt and Jersey" class="alternativeImage"  src="http://s21.postimg.org/ep27oalqr/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_1.jpg" width="54" height="54" >
        </li>
  </ul>
                </div>          

                </ul>
  </div>
```

black color html;

```
<p class="img-main">
<a href="/eshop/items/152MANH-KNM01S/152MANH-KNM01S-NY.jpg"    class="overlaybox-img" rel="NAVY">
<img src="http://s16.postimg.org/6y1xy2f91/HM10_T_1004_BK_1.jpg">
</a> </p>
<div id="colorsAndAltContainer">
<ul class="">

    <li class="defaultColor selected">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="description">BLACK</div>
                        <div class="rgbColor" data-color="000000" style="background-color: #000000"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="description">WHITE</div>
                        <div class="rgbColor" data-color="FFFFFF" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>

    <div class="altImages">

    <ul class="alternativeImages">     
    <li class="selected">

        </li>
        <li>
            <img  alt="http://s4.postimg.org/6ualhzpex/HM10_T_BACKLOGOLESS_BK.jpg" width="54"  height="54" >
        </li>
   </ul>
                </div>          

                </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
body{
background-color: #000;

 }
.img-main {
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
}
#colorsAndAltContainer {
position: relative;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 70px;
height: 300px;
float: left;
margin-left: 6px;
}
.inner {
cursor: pointer;
}
.description {
display: none;
}
.rgbColor {
border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
width: 13px;
height: 13px;
}
.selectColor {
float: left;
}

.selectColor ul {
float: left;
margin-right: 6px;
}
ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 0px;
}
.altImages {
position: absolute;
width: 70px;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
.alternativeImages {
bottom: 0;
}
.alternativeImages li {
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 6px;
}
img {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: this is how i want it to be when zoom http://s9.postimg.org/4xhwklc33/zoom.gif

Answer (score 0):

[Zoom.js](http://fat.github.io/zoom.js/) is a great javascript library to zoom in images.

Example:

```
<link href="css/zoom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/zoom.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/js/transition.js"></script>

<img src="http://s9.postimg.org/4xhwklc33/zoom.gif" data-action="zoom">
```

Good Luck Hope This Helps!

Note: I know github is not a good CDN but, it needs this script!